# How to scroll the last item to the top of the list view

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

My list view has a button that can scroll all contents up the screen, leaving only the last item in the screen. However, the default ScrollPosition's jumpTo method automatically constrains the scrolling offset to the maxScrollExtent after jumping. How can I achieve this effect

I found a similar effect

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RTY6HNAarZdYO71tTHO0oP1h4V6x2kEa/view?usp=share_link

thanks

Comment: Can You pls provide 1) What is your list doing now, 2) what you tried so far. (And maybe, a sketch what it should do.)

Otherwise, if it is enough, make the list not scrollable, make shrink wrap ture, wrap it in column, add the the column children to the end a 'const Spacer()' -> Its like an empty Expanded Widget. Then wrap the column with SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: @MrOrhan Basically my list is a chat box, I tried scrollController.jumpTo, but ScrollPosition automatically adjusts to the range after jumpTo ends, the problem with Column is that the performance may not be enough, if the list items are very large, LIst performance will be a little better

Comment: Pleas provide some code, what you are doing.

Comment: Ok I tried some workarounds, but its really hard to achieve but possible. It depends on what purpose your app is for and so on... good luck!

Comment: @MrOrhan I have read the code related to ScrollController and ScrollPosition. It seems that ScrollPosition cannot customize maxScrollExtent or adjust the method of limiting the scrolling range. It looks like I need to implement my own ListView.

Comment: If you know how much space there should be after the list ends, you can add a sizedbox at the end of the list with hight of 0 or 1, then you can add the real last item a padding with the height different you wish to the bottom. That is one of the workarounds. But I would prefer the first one. But If you have a Chat app, remember that even in whatsapp you have your chats always aligning to the bottom!